# Class not compiling

Tags: java, compiler-errors

We have been writing a java project and have come across an error when trying to compile. It is highlighting an error saying :

```
              ^
  symbol:   class Race
  location: class CyclingPortalImpl
CyclingPortalImpl.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
                        throw new IDNotRecognisedException("Race ID not recognised");
```

for every Exception we have written.

Thank you

We have double checked our packages and everything is where we believe it should be. Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated!

Comment: Well presumably there's no such class as `IDNotRecognisedException`, at least in terms of what's been provided to the compiler... or it's not been imported. Without a [mcve] we can't say anything more than that.

Comment: Or if there is such a class somewhere, you are missing the `import` declaration for it.

Comment: Please check out **in depth** [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Comment: looks like it is missing the `Race` class, according the "symbol:   class Race" error message. (`throw new IDNotRecognisedException` is probably part of the next error, which was not posted) -- eventually missing an `import`, as already commented; or missing the class in the current package (misspelled?)